# TypeError: expected a character buffer object when doing open()

Tags: python, compiler-errors

So I'm learning Python. I was doing a simple thing with arrays and open(), and sometimes this code works, and sometimes it doesn't! Please help!

```
    print('Load? (Y/N)')
load = raw_input()
if load == "y":
    fin = open("myArr.bat", "r")
    myArr = fin.readline()
if load == "n":
    myArr = [0, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0]
if load != "y" and load != "n":
    print 'WUT?'
    exit()

print (myArr[0]) ,  '|' ,  (myArr[1]) ,  '|' ,  (myArr [2])
print '----------'
print (myArr[3]) ,  '|' ,  (myArr[4]) ,  '|' ,  (myArr [5])
print '----------'
print (myArr[6]) ,  '|' ,  (myArr[7]) ,  '|' ,  (myArr [8])
print '_______________________________________________'
print 'What shall I change?'
print 'Number in array: '
foo = raw_input()
doo = int(float(foo))
print 'Number to change to: '
bar = raw_input()
dar = int(float(bar))
myArr[doo] = dar
print '_______________________________________________'
print (myArr[0]) ,  '|' ,  (myArr[1]) ,  '|' ,  (myArr [2])
print '----------'
print (myArr[3]) ,  '|' ,  (myArr[4]) ,  '|' ,  (myArr [5])
print '----------'
print (myArr[6]) ,  '|' ,  (myArr[7]) ,  '|' ,  (myArr [8])
fout = open("myArr.bat", "w")
fout.write(myArr)
fout.close()
```

Its giving me this :

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Screen.py", line 35, in <module>
    fout.write(myArr)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Please help!

Answer (score 11):

That's because the [`write`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) method expects a string as the first argument, but you're passing it an array.

Comment: Well how to I pass as a string, and how would I then later retrieve it? ty for thy help!

Comment: @PlazmotechBinary, if you want to store the serialized data from the array in a file, then later read the file and unserialize it, use  [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to guess that you get this error when you test your code and input `'n'`, but when you input `'y'`, it works just fine. This is because of these lines:

```
if load == "n":
myArr = [0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0]
```

This makes `myArr` a `list`. One does not simply write a list to a file. You must convert it into a string first (only strings can be written to files).

So depending on how you want to store this list in your file, you could do this:

```
fout = open("myArr.bat", "w")
fout.write(' '.join(map(str, myArr)))
fout.close()
```

This would essentially write the following line to `myArr.bat` (assuming `myArr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`):

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hmm... well, how would I then retrieve it? The only way I could think of would be: `fin = open("myArr.bat", "r")
myArr[0] = fin.readline(1)`
But that wouldn't work... because you have those spaces. But If I remove the spaces then you would have problems with 2 digit numbers... how can I do this?

Comment: `myArr = map(int, open("myArr.bat").readline().strip().split())` If you don't specify `"r"` in `open`, `"r"` is used as the default mode